# How to restart an lapply loop within a renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I am trying to create a shiny code that is able to filter a table non pre-determined number of times. When the user uploads a different (new) table, unfortunately the code breaks as I need to restart a lapply loop somehow, throwing out the previously stored column names.

I would like to create an non pre-defined filtering options for a table within Shiny. The user can select a column and filter a table choosing different categorical variables within that column. It is possible to add additional selection fields by pressing the 'Add' button.

the UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("testing of dynamic number of selection"),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("buttons")),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("drops")
    ,tableOutput("table")
  )
))
```

The server:

A table (test.csv) is automatically stored in a reactive values and a first searching field appears with 3 buttons (Add = to add a new searching field by reading in the colnames and a multiselect that stores the unique variables from that columns. The filtering function is activated by the Calculate button)

```
server<-function(input, output, session) {  

###### read in test file
values<-reactiveValues(number = 1,
                    upload = NULL,
                    input = NULL)

values$upload<-read.csv("test.csv")

#just the "add" button, in this instance it shouldn't be a uiOutput
output$buttons <- renderUI({
  div(
    actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add"), actionButton(inputId = "calc", label = "Calculate"),
    actionButton(inputId = "new", label = "new table")
  )
})

#pressing the add button
observeEvent(input$add, {
  cat("i adding a new record\n")
  values$number  <- values$number + 1L })

daStuff <- function(i){  
  inputName<-paste0("drop", i)
  inputName2<-paste0("select", i)
  inputText<-if(values$number>0){input[[paste0("drop",i)]]}else{F} # previously selected value for dropdown
  inputSelect <- if(values$number>1){input[[paste0("select",i)]]}else{F} # previously selected value for dropdown
  fluidRow(
    column(6,selectInput(inputName, inputName, c(colnames(values$upload)), selected = inputText)),   
    column(6,selectInput(inputName2, inputName2,                     
    na.omit(unique(as.vector(values$upload[,input[[paste0("drop",i)]]]))),
                         multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE, selected=inputSelect)) )}

output$drops<- renderUI({
  lapply(seq_len(values$number), daStuff)})
```

By pressing the Calculate button, the uploaded table is subjected to filtering, depending on the selected unique values and shown in the output$table

```
observeEvent(input$calc, {
   values$input<-NULL
    for (i in 1:values$number){
      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("select",i)]])){
        if(is.null(values$input)){
          values$input<- filter(values$upload,values$upload[,input[[paste0("drop",i)]]] %in% input[[paste0("select",i)]])}
        else{
          values$input<- filter(values$input,values$input[,input[[paste0("drop",i)]]] %in% input[[paste0("select",i)]])}
      } }
   if (is.null(values$input)){values$input<-values$upload}

   output$table <- renderTable({values$input}) 
   })
```

My problem is when I upload a new table (test2.csv), I don't know how to erase the previously stored selections (drop* and select* values) and gives back an error message.

```
 observeEvent(input$new,{
   values$upload<-read.csv("test2.csv")
})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

I suppose I should stop somehow the `lapply` loop and restart it over, so the previously stored values are replaced depending on the new selection, but I am a bit stuck on how I could achieve that.

Comment: I would replace lapply with a while loop where at each iteration I would look at a flag indicating whether I need to delete stuff and restart the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you might still be looking for solutions, I wanted to share something that was similar and could potentially be adapted for your needs.

This uses `observeEvent` for all select inputs. If it detects any changes, it will update all inputs, including the possibilities for `select` based on `drop`.

In addition, when a new file is read, the `selectInput` for `drop` and `select` are reset to first value.

**Edit**: I forgot to keep `selected = input[[paste0("drop",i)]]` in place for the dropdown (see revised code). It seems to keep the values now when new filters are added - let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

myDataFrame <- read.csv("test.csv")

ui <- shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Testing of dynamic number of selection"),
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose file to upload", accept = ".csv"),
      uiOutput("buttons")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("inputs"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myInputs <- reactiveValues(rendered = c(1))

  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      d <- myDataFrame
    } else {
      d <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    }
    d
  })

  observeEvent(lapply(paste0("drop", myInputs$rendered), function(x) input[[x]]), {
    for (i in myInputs$rendered) {
      updateSelectInput(session, 
                       paste0('select', i), 
                       choices = myData()[input[[paste0('drop', i)]]],
                       selected = input[[paste0("select",i)]])
    }
  })

  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    div(
      actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add"), 
      actionButton(inputId = "calc", label = "Calculate")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    myInputs$rendered <- c(myInputs$rendered, max(myInputs$rendered)+1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$calc, {
    showData <- NULL
    for (i in 1:length(myInputs$rendered)) {
      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("select",i)]])) {
        if(is.null(showData)) {
          showData <- filter(myData(), myData()[,input[[paste0("drop",i)]]] %in% input[[paste0("select",i)]])
        }
        else {
          showData <- filter(showData, showData[,input[[paste0("drop",i)]]] %in% input[[paste0("select",i)]])
        }
      }
    }
    if (is.null(showData)) { showData <- myData() }
    output$table <- renderTable({showData}) 
  })

  observe({
    output$inputs <- renderUI({
      rows <- lapply(myInputs$rendered, function(i){
        fluidRow(
          column(6,  selectInput(paste0('drop',i), 
                               label = "", 
                               choices = colnames(myData()), 
                               selected = input[[paste0("drop",i)]])),
          column(6,  selectInput(paste0('select',i),
                               label = "",
                               choices = myData()[1],
                               multiple = TRUE,
                               selectize = TRUE))
        )
      })
      do.call(shiny::tagList, rows)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, that is a useful solution, although the only problem is that when the 'Add' button is pressed, it does not store the previously selected options.

Comment: Please see edits. I forgot to replace `selected = input[[paste0("drop",i)]]` for the `selectInput` for `drop`. It seems to work at my end. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.